# What is this fungus?

Tags: identification, fungus

We found this fungus and are not sure what it is. Any help is much appreciated; thank you

[image]

Comment: Where did you find it - was it growing upwards as in your hand, or attached to the side of a tree trunk or similar? Are there any stalks?

Comment: It was in our mulch, growing upwards. Underneath a tree. Didn't see any stalks, no.

Answer (score 1):

This looks very like [Otidea onotica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otidea_onotica) commonly growing on wood mulch ; In France we call this *Hare's Ear*.

### edit suggested by Stephi

I'm pretty sure it is that one, even if wikipedia pictures is a little too colored. Here's [another place to confirm](http://www.first-nature.com/fungi/otidea-onotica.php).

Comment: That seems to be a bit hasty - Pezziales, including the genus otidea, are a quite diverse group. And the specimen in this question look different than the ones in the link you gave. With mushrooms, an id based on one photo can be risky, *especially if you suggest edibility*.

Comment: I removed my edibility suggest.